# Is there a way to change the default animation speed in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I do a lot of PowerPoint (2007) presentations, and some of those involve some rather complex diagrams that I like to build step by step, using PowerPoint's animation feature.

I prefer using the "fade in" style, but I find the default medium speed setting too low, so every time I'm adding an element to my animation, I have to go to the Speed dropdown box and select "Very fast". This is getting annoying, so I wonder if there is a way to tell PowerPoint that I'd like my standard animation speed (at least for fade-ins) to be "very fast"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this option is not available.

However, I found [this post](http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-office-powerpoint/392216-set-default-animation-speed-powerpoint.html#post1576779) which uses VBA code to loop through your slides and change the speed.

Comment: Hm, OK, thanks. Not really what I was looking for, but if it's not there, there's not much I can do...

Answer (score 2):

As best I've been able to determine, you can't change the default settings for animations, which is complete nonsense on Microsoft's part.  There is a solution in your case though.  In Powerpoint 2010 the default animation speed for fade-ins is very fast (0.5 seconds), so if you upgrade that particular problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find what you (and I) were looking for, but the built-in "**[Animation Painter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/duplicate-animations-with-the-animation-painter-f2246f1c-87b4-4cb3-81fa-336e538ba8c8)**" can save you a lot of time. It is like the "Format Painter", but for animations.

Select one object with the animations already sorted, then click the "Animation Painter", then click all the other objects one after the other, and it will duplicate the animation(s) from the original object to the other objects. You don't even need to first add the animations to the other objects.

"Animations" tab -> "Advanced Animation" section -> "Animation Painter"

The shortcut is useful:

Alt+Shift+C

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a macro, using the Macro Recorder in Office 2003, which usually can transfer to Office 2007. However, it recorded nothing, indicating that a macro can’t be created for this. You will probably need to use the *Appear* command, which rather than fading in, causes the object to appear instantly. However, that is much better than the `Medium` setting, which is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is set up your first slide and do it with just **one** quick animation
(Use the numbers you want as your defaults)

Then, "Duplicate the slide".  (Your default was just saved)
Delete that animation.
Duplicate as many slides as you think you will need for your build.
(Remember, only the duplication keeps the new animation default setting)

If you click on "Add New Slide", that is telling the system, to go to the originally created system defaults.